# On the Fourier transform of Dirac measure

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-transform

Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure with compact support on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\hat{\mu}(\xi)=\int e^{-2\pi i\xi x}d\mu(x)$ denote the Fourier transform of $\mu$.
Is the following claim true?

**$\mu$ is not a Dirac measure if and ony if $|\hat{\mu}(\xi)|\not\equiv1, \xi\in \mathbb{R}.$**

We know that if $\mu$ is a Dirac measure on $\mathbb{R}$, then $|\hat{\mu}(\xi)|\equiv1, \xi\in \mathbb{R},$  So, the sufficiency is true. Is the other hand true?

Comment: @geetha290krm No, the Bernoulli distribution is an obvious counterexample https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $|\int e^{-2\pi i \xi x} \mu(dx)| = 1$.

Fix $\xi$. Thanks to the equality case in the integral triangular inequality [Equality in the triangle inequality for integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491235/equality-in-the-triangle-inequality-for-integrals), it means that there is $\theta$ such that $e^{-2\pi i \xi x} = e^{i\theta}$ for $\mu$-almost every $x$.

That means that $2\pi \xi x \in \theta + 2\pi \mathbb Z$, in other words, $x \in \dfrac {\theta}{\xi} + \dfrac 1 \xi \mathbb Z$ for $\mu$-almost every $x$.

Now consider $\xi_1, \xi_2$such that $\dfrac {\xi_1}{\xi_2} \notin \mathbb Q$. For $\mu$-a.e. $x$ we have
$$x \in (\dfrac {\theta_1}{\xi_1} + \dfrac 1 {\xi_1} \mathbb Z)\cap(\dfrac {\theta_2}{\xi_2} + \dfrac 1 {\xi_2} \mathbb Z)$$

But this latter set cannot have more than one point (easy to show, if two distinct points, $\dfrac {\xi_1}{\xi_2} \in \mathbb Q$).
This just says that the support of $\mu$ is a single point.

Comment: Many thanks! @justt

Comment: Thank you, happy learning. The other answer is much more elegant in my opinion though !

Comment: How to understand the last statement? i.e, You can do that for 2 different ξ which are not commensurable. This implies that x is constant for μ-almost every x.  Would you like to give some further comments?Thanks!

Comment: Edited to answer

Comment: Many thanks for your kind reply! I think the constant $\theta$ depends on $\xi$, and $x\in \frac{\theta}{2\pi \xi}+\frac{1}{\xi}\mathbb{Z}$. How to prove that the set $(\frac{\theta_{\xi_1}}{2\pi \xi_1}+\frac{1}{\xi_1}\mathbb{Z})\cap (\frac{\theta_{\xi_2}}{2\pi \xi_2}+\frac{1}{\xi_2}\mathbb{Z})$ cannot have more than one point?

Comment: You're perfectly right. It's $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. 

Consider two distinct points in the intersection. What can be said of their difference ?

Comment: I got it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here is a probabilistic argument: Let $X,Y$ be i.i.d with law $\mu$. Then the characteristic function of $X-Y$ is $|\hat {\mu}|^{2}=1$. This implies that $X=Y$ a.s. But $X$ and $Y$ are independent , so $X$ must be  a constant.

Comment: Many thanks! @geentha290krm